# CustomAnnotationView with a button

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've been strunggling with an issue on my project :

I've a mapView and I have to show the annotation presented below (The small (+) is my button)

[image: what's I have to do]

I've subclassed MKAnnotationView and I have CustomAnnotationView.h like this :

```
@interface CustomAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *calloutView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *pinButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *annView;

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)animateCalloutAppearance;
```

My CustomAnnotationView.m

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];


    if(selected)
    {
        //building my custom animation 
        annView = [[ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)) ];

        annView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);

        calloutView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customcallout.png"]];


        [calloutView setFrame:CGRectMake(-25, 50, 0, 0)];
        [calloutView sizeToFit];


        [self animateCalloutAppearance];

        //I tried to add a button here but I could't do it like it should be
        [annView addSubview:calloutView];

        [self addSubview:annView];

    }
    else
    {
        //Remove your custom view...

        [annView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview{


        if ([[[subview class] description] isEqualToString:@"UICalloutView"]) {
            for (UIView *subsubView in subview.subviews) {
                if ([subsubView class] == [UIImageView class]) {
                    UIImageView *imageView = ((UIImageView *)subsubView);
                    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
                }else if ([subsubView class] == [UILabel class]) {
                    UILabel *labelView = ((UILabel *)subsubView);
                    [labelView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }

    }
}


- (void)animateCalloutAppearance {
    CGFloat scale = 0.001f;
    calloutView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, 0, -50);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        CGFloat scale = 1.1f;
        calloutView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, 0, 2);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            CGFloat scale = 0.95;
            calloutView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, 0, -2);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.075 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                CGFloat scale = 1.0;
                calloutView.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0.0f, 0.0f, scale, 0, 0);

            } completion:nil];
        }];
    }];
}

@end
```

With this I'm able to show my custom annotation on the map but I can't figure out how to place a button on it and this button should of course be able to respond to clicks like the callback `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`

Please anyone with a working example code or idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this using `- (UIView*)hitTest` in my `CustmAnnotationView.m` class. I have a separate nib for the callout view and use hittest to determine whether the UILabel named `directionsButton` (linked from the callout nib) was clicked:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (selected) {
        calloutVisible = YES;
        hitTestBuffer = NO;
        self.calloutView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CalloutView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];  
        [directionsButton setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Medium" size:12.0f]];
        [calloutView setFrame:CGRectMake(calloutView.frame.origin.x, calloutView.frame.origin.y, 280, calloutView.frame.size.height)];          
        [calloutView setAlpha:0.0f];    
        [self addSubview:calloutView];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:calloutView];


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{     
            [calloutView setAlpha:1.0f];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    } else {
        calloutVisible = NO;

        CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
        newFrame.size.width = 52;
        self.frame = newFrame;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{
            [calloutView setAlpha:0.0f];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [calloutView removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }
}


- (void)directionsPressed
{
    if ([parent respondsToSelector:@selector(directionsPressed:)])
        [parent performSelector:@selector(directionsPressed:) withObject:self.stockist];
}


- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (calloutVisible) {
        CGPoint hitPoint = [calloutView convertPoint:point toView:directionsButton];
        if ([calloutView pointInside:hitPoint withEvent:event]) {
            if (!hitTestBuffer) {
                [self directionsPressed];
                hitTestBuffer = YES;
            }
            return [directionsButton hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        } else {
            hitTestBuffer = NO;
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

In my code `parent` is my current VC. This is probably not the neatest way but it worked at the time.

The callout looks like this:

[image: callout]

A couple of booleans `calloutVisible` and `hitTestBuffer` make sure the button is only clickable once and only when visible.

Comment: can you catch the click on your VC to be able to show directions ? and how ?

Comment: The line  `[parent performSelector:@selector(directionsPressed:) withObject:self.stockist];` in my original post calls my view controller (`parent`) to show a directions overlay.

Comment: I accepted your answer and gave you the bounty points , as a favor is it possible to upload a demo project for this solution ? it will be very much appreciated .

Comment: Hi there, are you still looking for a demo project covering this?

Answer (score 2):

To try and resolve your issue, I played a bit with [Apple's WeatherMap example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html), and came up with a working solution to your problem.

I added your code to the `WeatherAnnotationView.m` file (minus the animation code), and on top of that added the code to display the button, and respond to touch events:

```
-(void)annotationButtonClicked{
    NSLog(@"** button clicked");
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    if(selected)
    {
        //building my custom animation
        annView = [[ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)) ];

        annView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);

        calloutView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudy.png"]];


        [calloutView setFrame:CGRectMake(-25, 50, 0, 0)];
        [calloutView sizeToFit];
        [annView addSubview:calloutView];


        /* BUTTON CODE */
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [annView addSubview:button];
        /* END Of BUTTON CODE */

        [self addSubview:annView];

    }
    else
    {
        //Remove your custom view...
        [annView removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

You haven't posted HOW you tried to add a button to the `annView`, so it is hard for me to understand what was not working with your approach. A common approach for these kind of problems is to remove one piece of code at a time and try to run your app. For starters, try to remove the animation code. Then, try to remove `calloutView`, and remain only with `annView` and the button, until you have code that works with a button. After that, add back the pieces you removed earlier (animation, `calloutView`) one at a time and see which one is causing your button to stop function.

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , actually I tried this already , the issue with this code is that I need to have the callback method of this button somewhere else (in my VC)

Comment: Do you have access to your VC from CustomAnnotationView.m? or, firing an event in CustomAnnotationView.m and have the VC catch it?

Comment: I don't have an access to my VC from my CustomAnnotationView.m class.I need to catch the button action click on the VC like a normal accessory callout button would do .